# How to retrieve Attribute Display name from CRM 4.0 Plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

How can I get the Display name of Custom Attribute from CRM Plugin? This code doesn't give me the name. Please let me know. Thank you

```
            DynamicEntity entity = (DynamicEntity)context.InputParameters.Properties["Target"];
            String str = (String)entity.Properties["name"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to make a call to the MetadataService to get the AttributeMetadata which has a DisplayName property.

Comment: Do I have to reference MetadataService?

Comment: Using the MetadataService works the same as the normal CrmService. In a plugin, you just call `context.CreateMetadataService()` to get it.

Comment: I got this working: IMetadataService metadataService = context.CreateMetadataService(false); But I couldn't get this line working. RetrieveAttributeRequest attributeRequest = new RetrieveAttributeRequest();